# Firing a UIButton instantly

Tags: ios, uibutton

Right now I have a square button like so

OFF

[image]

[image]

ON
I want the button to change instantly when I first press on it (not wait for the finger to be lifted), so I need it to fire instantly and only once because I will also include a long press gesture for a different action. How would I go about making the button behave like this? Right now it only works for when I lift my finger off. (all the config has been done in the interface builder).

EDIT:

As liushuaikobe explained below I have set the event to "Touch Down" now. The button is now firing correctly but the image won't change until I take my finger off:

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"button pressed");
    button.selected = YES;
}
```

The button should be selected instantly, I have the off image set in the interface builder for default and the on one set for selected. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a action for the button on state `UIControlEventTouchDown`.

This is the state when button is "pressed" rather than the finger left the screen (which is called `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`).

[image]

Comment: Okay got this, my button is firing instantly now and only once as required, but the image won't change instantly. The image only changes when I lift my finger. I'm my buttonPressed method I instantly change the button to selected with button.selected = YES; In the interface builder I have the default image set as the off one and the selected button set to the on one.

Answer (score 2):

Connect your button action to your file owner with `Touch Down` event like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your button connected with IBoutlet then you can do it by this way

```
 [switchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(forgotBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an image for the state highlighted:
[yourButton setImage: yourImage forState: UIControlStateHighlighted].

Answer (score -1):

Set your `highlighted` image (`UIButton`'s property) as `on.png`, assuming that `default` is `off.png` only if you want the effect not the method to be called, if you need your method to be called on press down then you have to change your control event from `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to `UIControlEventTouchDown`

[image]